# jQuery “data” attribute doesn't W3C validate

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm wondering why this bit of html doesn't validate (XHTML 1.0 transitional) because of the "data" attribute. I've searched around for answers, and I'm not using the jQuery metadata plugin, if that matters.

Any way to get this to validate, or escape it so the validator doesn't see it?

```
<div id="home" data-image="images/water.jpg">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `data` attributes are [part of the HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to specify the HTML 5 doctype.