# W3C validation for Twitter widget

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, w3c-validation

I use  `Twitter Widget` in my application [asp.net c#].
My code is:

```
StringBuilder strTwittsViewer = new StringBuilder();
strTwittsViewer.Append("</span><span class='cssClassFollowButton'><a href=\"https://twitter.com/Shree\" class=\"twitter-follow-button\" data-show-count=\"false\">Follow @Shree</a>");
strTwittsViewer.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script></span></p>");
```

but my code unable to pass [W3C validation](http://validator.w3.org/).I got a error 
`there is no attribute "data-show-count"
…witter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @shree</a><script typ…`
I search and find [this solution](http://www.newtechtips.org/tips-and-tricks-to-validate-w3c-for-facebook-fbml-twitter-google-1-and-youtube/) but unable to understand how to implement this solution with my code.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because data attributes are part of the [HTML 5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to specify the HTML 5 doctype

*Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827697/jquery-data-attribute-doesnt-w3c-validate)*

**OR**

Put your link code into document.write so you'll have

```
strTwittsViewer.Append(@"<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">");
strTwittsViewer.Append(@"//<![CDATA[");
strTwittsViewer.Append(@"document.write('<span class=""cssClassFollowButton""><a href=\""https://twitter.com/Shree\"" class=\""twitter-follow-button\"" data-show-count=\""false\"">Follow @Shree</a>"");");
strTwittsViewer.Append(@"//]]>");
strTwittsViewer.Append(@"</script>");
```

Comment: You can set doctype only on entire page