# In social networking getting W3c error

Tags: javascript, html, social-networking, w3c-validation

I use some social network functionality for my site for that i add

```
<div class="share-buttons share-buttons-tab" data-buttons="twitter,facebook,google,pinterest" data-style="medium" data-counter="true" data-hover="true" data-promo-callout="true" data-float="left"></div>
```

and i get w3c error for the attribute which is reside in this div

1. data-buttons
2. data-style
3. data-counter
4. data-hover
5. data-promo-callout

So how can i solve this

Below is screenshot of w3c validation

[image: error list in w3c site validation]

I got some thing like this in my page source

```
<html class="javascript wf-myriadpro-n4-active wf-myriadpro-n6-active wf-myriadpro-n7-active wf-leaguegothic-n4-active wf-active" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
```

in red color is this problem?

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827697/jquery-data-attribute-doesnt-w3c-validate Just add the `HTML5` doctype, instead of the one you're using now. As the `data-` attributes are in the `HTML5 spec`

Comment: i getting this error when i added <!DOCTYPE> **Line 3, Column 3: "DOCTYPE" declaration not allowed in instance** @NickR

Comment: No idea, without actually seeing your HTML.

Comment: Now i added code in which i set <!DOCTYPE html> please check it @NickR

Comment: Now i am not above **Line 3, Column 3: "DOCTYPE" declaration not allowed in instance** error but still error of w3c is remain same @NickR

Comment: Check this : http://pastebin.com/791SdkmV This is the basic page structure for an `HTML5` page

Comment: I added same code as you suggest in my page but still have a same problem and i also edit my question i got doc type in my page which i added in last @NickR

Comment: Post the full `html` output of the page, from the very top `doctype` declaration to the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: That site displays the following `doctype` - `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Yes i change that but still remain same there for i ask to you @NickR

Comment: this is my Bigcommerce site@NickR

Comment: I don't know, maybe because it's a hosted solution, I don't know if you can change the `doctype`, it might be worth contacting BigCommerce then?

Comment: Yes now i try to contact BC support. Thanks for your great effort @NickR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of My Question for that i need to set `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 %%Panel.HTMLHead%%
<body>
```

**Now all the the error are solve it just because of the page DOCTYPE is not HTML 5**

```
**data-buttons
data-style
data-counter
data-hover
data-promo-callout**
```

This all attribute support in **HTML5**. I got this after long research.

I hope this will also help to other.